# Using Local File in Spring Yarn application

Tags: spring-boot, hadoop-yarn

i need deploy the war file on yarn container for that  I am using Spring batch for creating a yarn application that uses embedded jetty server to deploy a war file,when i use a customhandle for handling the request it works fine the application get deployed on yarn but when i use war file as a handler it doesnt works i get a error

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/jettywebapps/webapps/Login.war`

but the file is actually present at the given location i am stuck how to access the war file from the yarn container

```
@OnContainerStart
    public void publicVoidNoArgsMethod() throws Exception {
        String jetty_home="/root/jettywebapps";
        Server server = new Server(9090);
        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
        webapp.setContextPath("/Login");
        webapp.setWar(jetty_home+"/webapps/Login.war");
        server.setHandler(webapp);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
```

Here is the Stack Trace

```
2015-04-17 06:05:14.972] boot - 26920  INFO [main] --- ContainerLauncherRunner: Running YarnContainer with parameters []
[2015-04-17 06:05:14.972] boot - 26920  INFO [main] --- ContainerLauncherRunner: Container requested that we wait state, setting up latch
[2015-04-17 06:05:14.975] boot - 26920  INFO [main] --- DefaultYarnContainer: Processing 1 @YarnComponent handlers
[2015-04-17 06:05:15.038] boot - 26920  INFO [main] --- Server: jetty-8.0.4.v20111024
[2015-04-17 06:05:15.080] boot - 26920  WARN [main] --- WebInfConfiguration: Web application not found /root/jettywebapps/webapps/Login.war
[2015-04-17 06:05:15.081] boot - 26920  WARN [main] --- WebAppContext: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/Login,null},/root/jettywebapps/webapps/Login.war
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/jettywebapps/webapps/Login.war
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.unpack(WebInfConfiguration.java:479)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.preConfigure(WebInfConfiguration.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:416)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:452)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
        at hello.container.HelloPojo.publicVoidNoArgsMethod(HelloPojo.java:40)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:112)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:129)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:342)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:330)
        at org.springframework.yarn.support.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:126)
        at org.springframework.yarn.container.ContainerMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(ContainerMethodInvokerHelper.java:229)
        at org.springframework.yarn.container.ContainerMethodInvokerHelper.process(ContainerMethodInvokerHelper.java:115)
        at org.springframework.yarn.container.MethodInvokingYarnContainerRuntimeProcessor.process(MethodInvokingYarnContainerRuntimeProcessor.java:51)
        at org.springframework.yarn.container.ContainerHandler.handle(ContainerHandler.java:99)
        at org.springframework.yarn.container.DefaultYarnContainer.getContainerHandlerResults(DefaultYarnContainer.java:174)
        at org.springframework.yarn.container.DefaultYarnContainer.runInternal(DefaultYarnContainer.java:77)
```

please help
Thanks

Comment: i solved this by using local resource in yarn,so before my containers starts all the file that are marked as local resources will be available at the containers directory before containers starts,For more info check this liink     http://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/springandhadoop-yarn.html#local-resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the container could fetch local files or hdfs files using following code:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem localFS = FileSystem.get(URI.create("file://localhost"), conf);
OutputStream outATXT = localFS.create(new Path("/home/walterchen/a.txt"));
```

or

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create("hdfs://localhost:9000"), conf);
OutputStream out = fs.create(new Path("/home/a.txt"));
```